# How do you install Slate in an existing Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'd like to install Slate (API docs) in an existing Rails app and hopefully without running middleman. Are there tutorials on how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can't "install" it. What you can do is run `bundle exec middleman build --clean` within the slate repo, then take the generated static files from the `build` directory and copy them to a Rails repo (the `public` folder), where you can then deploy them and set routes to them in `routes.rb`.

Comment: Is there something else that needs to get modified? I followed this and was able to get the html to show, but the stylesheets and javascripts were unable to be found. I copied the contents of the build folder in slate to my project, but wasn't able to get it to work